# Assets won't precompile when deploying with capistrano to production on amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I worked on being able to deploy to production using capistrano.  I face several issues and while fixing most of them we still have a last one.

Our precompile assets options are not properly compiling them on production and because of that, we are unable to use the last developed features as they rely heavily on JS.

Without trying to influence on how anyone would analyze this problem, this is some of what I did trying to make it work:

1. Precompiled assets locally, pushed to github repo, cap deployed from local machines to ec2. cap deploy is local, the code being pushed to ec2 is the one on github.
2. Tried using capistrano tasks as suggested.  Using load 'deploy'assets' in the Capfile and letting the cap deploy:setup task do its thing.
3. Used the option cap deploy:assets:clean and then cap deploy:assets:precompile
4. Tried removing assets from public and then use a pipeline_precompile task in deploy.rb
5. Expired assets, forcing rails to precompile everything changing assets.versions in application.rb
6. Tried different combinations on config.assets in environments/production.rb
7. Finally, tried deleting public/assets in production and precompiling up there using RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

The app is just not using the new JS files.  If you check the code either on the repo or in the server itself, I introduced a simple comment to the name.js.coffee ("# Shows and hides menus depending on the data on DB" on line xxx) and this is not in the compiled assets.js in production. This is a quick test to be sure the recent assets are being used.

The whole problem here is the js and css files, not so much rails. Which is why it is so difficult to test or find.. Thus one of the reasons for the popularity of js frameworks lately. In case of problems, you don't have to kill yourself looking for where the problem is.. If the prob is in ruby or rails, usually doesn't take that long to find out. Once you get to js, css and cross browser compatibility, well, this IS the problem at hand.

Here's my deploy.rb file. Running rails 3.2.12 ruby-1.9.3-p327:

```
# $:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))

# Load rvm's capistrono plugins
require 'rvm/capistrano'

require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :user, 'username'
set :domain, 'ip_address'
set :application, "app_pro"
set :keep_releases, 2 # It keeps on two old releases.

# git repo details
set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names
set :repository,  "git@github.com:user/app.git"
set :scm_username, 'user'
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :branch, 'master'

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`


role :web, domain                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true# 'ec2-23-23-156-118.compute-1.amazonaws.com' This is where Rails migrations will run
# role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

# deply options
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/Downloads/key.pem"]}
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/appdir"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do
    # run COMMAND="/etc/init.d/nginx restart" invoke SUDO=1
    run "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart"
    # exit
  end
  after "deploy:start", "deploy:cleanup"

  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts 'now edit the config file database in #{shared_path}'
  end
  after 'deploy:setup', 'deploy:setup_config'

  desc "Symlink shared resources on each release - not used"
  task :symlink_config, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  after 'deploy:finalize_update', 'deploy:symlink_config'

  desc "It helps to seed database with values"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
  task :create_schema do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} --trace"
  end
end
```

On-working new/alternative (deploy_new2.rb) file:

```
# On-working new/alternative deploy.rb file:

require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :application, "ip_address"
set :domain, 'ip_address'

# Roles
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

#deployment details
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "username"
set :copy_compression, :bz2
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/dir"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/Downloads/key.pem"]}

#repo details
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:user/app.git"
set :scm_username, 'user'
set :keep_releases, 2
set :branch, "master"


namespace :deploy do
  # task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   # not need to restart nginx every time
  #   # run "service nginx start"
  #   run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  # end

  # after "deploy:start", "deploy:cleanup"
  # after 'deploy:cleanup', 'deploy:symlink_config'

  # You do not need reload nginx every time, eventhought if you use passenger or unicorn
  # task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "service nginx stop"
  # end

  # task :graceful_stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "service nginx stop"
  # end

  # task :reload, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  #   run "service nginx restart"
  # end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  # If you enable assets/deploy in Capfile, you do not need this
  # task :pipeline_precompile do
  #   # run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  #   # precompile assets before deploy and upload them to server 
  #   # run_locally("RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake assets:clean && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake assets:precompile")
  #   # top.upload "public/assets", "#{release_path}/public/assets", :via =>:scp, :recursive => true
  # end
end

# you do not need to this, because you already add require 'bundler/capistrano'
# before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"
```

And ./Capfile:

```
load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Thank you in advance for any help! Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Anyone think  from the logs that it could be a caching problem?

Comment: Probably not, since you've tried expiring the assets.

Comment: I see "Rails Error: Unable to access log file" above. Good perhaps to remove the line, `log/*` from .gitignore (presuming you have `log/*.log` there already) and do `touch log/.gitkeep`, add, commit and deploy again, in order to see the deployment-time production log in /home/ubuntu/teamzoom_pro_set2/releases/*/log/production.log. Maybe the log directory is not there when unpacking from Git.

Comment: Your `cap deploy` output shows this is the log file during asset precompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Here's the working deploy file-

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :application, "ip_address"
set :domain, 'ip_address'

# Roles
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

#deployment details
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "user"
set :copy_compression, :bz2
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/app_dir"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/sites/app/config/key.pem"]}

#repo details
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:github_id/app.git"
set :scm_username, 'github_id'
set :keep_releases, 2
set :branch, "master"

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_db'

namespace :deploy do
  # task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   # not need to restart nginx every time
  #   # run "service nginx start"
  #   run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  # end

  # after "deploy:start", "deploy:cleanup"
  # after 'deploy:cleanup', 'deploy:symlink_config'

  # You do not need reload nginx every time, eventhought if you use passenger or unicorn
  # task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "service nginx stop"
  # end

  # task :graceful_stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "service nginx stop"
  # end

  # task :reload, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  #   run "service nginx restart"
  # end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Symlinks the database.yml"
  task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  # If you enable assets/deploy in Capfile, you do not need this
  # task :pipeline_precompile do
  #   # run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  #   # precompile assets before deploy and upload them to server 
  #   # run_locally("RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake assets:clean && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake assets:precompile")
  #   # top.upload "public/assets", "#{release_path}/public/assets", :via =>:scp, :recursive => true
  # end
end

# you do not need to this, because you already add require 'bundler/capistrano'
# before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"
```

Answer (score 15):

You don't need your own :precompile_assets task. You are using Capistrano's by including load 'deploy/assets' in your Capfile.

Removing the :precompile_assets task from your deploy.rb may resolve the issue. If you look at the source code for Capistrano, you'll see it implements :precompile_assets quite differently: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/legacy-v2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb

Comment: You don't need a :pipeline_precompile task actually. Take out all references to it. Capistrano has the logic to precompile built into it. If that still doesn't work, can you post the output that Capistrano logs. Cheers.

Comment: It should be Capitrano that precompiles assets once, for multiple identical instances.

Comment: Yes, I tried this with the deploy_new.rb on-working script above, but simply removing all refs to :pipeline_precompile didn't solve the issue. I also updated the capistrano stack above when running cap deploy. Please have a look.

Comment: Your logs show the precompile happeng. Can you see the updated assets if you ssh into the box and look in #{current_path}/public? Is your Apache/Passenger being restarted correctly by the cap task? What if you restart them manually?

Comment: I restarted them manually just to be sure that wouldn't be the issue.. And that wasn't the solution either. I am going to do the last suggestion, I'll add the variable instead of a comment.. Any other ideas ?

Comment: The whole problem here is the js and css files, not so much rails.  Which is why it is so difficult to test or find.. Thus one of the reasons for the popularity of js frameworks lately. In case of problems, you don't have to kill yourself looking for where the problem is.. If the prob is in ruby or rails, usually doesn't take that long to find out.  Once you get to js, css and cross browser compatibility, well, you've seen it. Thx

Comment: Do you have your js files in app/assets/javascripts?  Do you have a file ````app/assets/javascripts/application.js```` that has a require statement for each of your js files?

Comment: Lol, yes. I'm not new to Ruby/Rails.

Comment: Sorry, I only ask to rule it out. You have me stumped, my friend.

Comment: Link is 404. It seems like every link on the internet to this file is 404.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
# On-working new/alternative deploy.rb file:

require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :application, "ip_address"
set :domain, 'ip_address'

# Roles
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

#deployment details
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "username"
set :copy_compression, :bz2
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/dir"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :ssh_options, {:auth_methods => "publickey"}
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["~/Downloads/key.pem"]}

#repo details
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:user/app.git"
set :scm_username, 'user'
set :keep_releases, 2
set :branch, "master"


namespace :deploy do
  # task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   # not need to restart nginx every time
  #   # run "service nginx start"
  #   run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  # end

  # after "deploy:start", "deploy:cleanup"
  # after 'deploy:cleanup', 'deploy:symlink_config'

  # You do not need reload nginx every time, eventhought if you use passenger or unicorn
  # task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "service nginx stop"
  # end

  # task :graceful_stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "service nginx stop"
  # end

  # task :reload, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  #   run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  #   run "service nginx restart"
  # end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{release_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  # If you enable assets/deploy in Capfile, you do not need this
  # task :pipeline_precompile do
  #   # run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  #   # precompile assets before deploy and upload them to server 
  #   # run_locally("RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake assets:clean && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} rake assets:precompile")
  #   # top.upload "public/assets", "#{release_path}/public/assets", :via =>:scp, :recursive => true
  # end
end

# you do not need to this, because you already add require 'bundler/capistrano'
# before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"
```

Comment: Manually uploading the app & assets for now while I work out a better deploy solution, but this script works after I fixed numerous bugs related to a previous developer's work.

Comment: Got it. See final fixed version of deploy file below.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the capistrano asset compile rules got run before the bundler rules, so nothing worked, I wrote my own:

```
  after "bundle:install" do
    run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  end
```

I then found that I really wasn't interested in installing a js runtime on my production machines.  I went back to just putting my assets into a deploy branch of my git tree.
First time I did this, I forgot to include the manifest.yml file.

http://jimneath.org/2012/05/05/precompile-assets-using-a-git-hook.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have uglifier in Gemfile, which runs during asset compilation, it may have been configured to remove just the sort of comment you are using as a test for whether the changed Javascript assets are being deployed.

Uglifier's Readme [says](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier#usage) this is possible, and distinguishes several kinds of comments. So it's possible you may have been misled by seeing another comment still remaining after asset compilation.

Another clue to judging this possibility is that (as you say) this problem arose after a long (tiring) process of fixing other problems. Often, this can block people from a perception like this; a long effort can 'lock them in' to an assumption.

So, try adding a variable declaration instead of a comment, in your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this but the solution was to remove the assets group in the Gemfile, as the default task cap uses to precompile depends on the assets not being in a separate group seemingly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem. Turns out I had to install node and yarn on my servers for rake assets:precompile to work

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue recently, asset precompilation with Capistrano deployment was hanging in AWS. I solved the issue by switching from a t3.micro instance to a t3.small instance temporarily while I deployed. It looks like the micro instance did not have enough resources for the precompilation step.